# compiled javascript path resolution error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am using paths in typescript It works fine with tsc-watch but when I generate the js build file and run it with node dist/main.js I get this

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@config/typeorm.config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kronos/nestjs-backend/dist/app.module.js:11:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

My tsconfig.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": [
        "./utils/*"
      ],
      "@dto/*": [
        "./dto/*"
      ],
      "@middlewares/*": [
        "./middlewares/*"
      ],
      "@modules/*": [
        "./modules/*"
      ],
      "@config/*": [
        "./config/*"
      ]
    },
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your code that may Include your `typeorm` and `path` thing that makes your build error. It seems can't find sub dependency you could look at `node_modules` and see is there are `typeorm.config` or not

Comment: typeorm.config is a file